How can a player track the use of an item? RocketMod
My task. When a player uses an item (for example, drinks milk), he must be healed. I tried to solve this with crutches, for example, by disappearing an item from the inventory.
Also via the UseableConsumeable event.
I don't know where to go. I ask for your help
One of the examples of my failed code
    using Rocket.Core.Plugins;
    using Rocket.Unturned.Enumerations;
    using Rocket.Unturned.Events;
    using Rocket.Unturned.Player;
    using SDG.Unturned;
    using UnityEngine;

    namespace PronePlugin
    {
        public class ProneOnLowHealth : RocketPlugin
    {
            Player player;
            //private const int HealthThreshold = 50;
            ```
            protected override void Load()
            {
                UnturnedPlayerEvents.OnPlayerInventoryRemoved += 
    UnturnedPlayerEvents_OnPlayerInventoryRemoved;
            }
            ```
            private void 
    UnturnedPlayerEvents_OnPlayerInventoryRemoved(UnturnedPlayer 
    player, InventoryGroup inventoryGroup, byte inventoryIndex, ItemJar 
    itemJar)
            {
                UnturnedPlayer uplayer = 
    UnturnedPlayer.FromPlayer(player.Player);
                ItemAsset itemAsset = itemJar.GetAsset();

                PlayerInputPacket packet = new PlayerInputPacket();
                if (inventoryGroup == InventoryGroup.Hands && 
    inventoryIndex == 0)
                {
                    if (itemAsset != null && itemAsset.id == 462)
                    {
                        ChatManager.serverSendMessage("Compleate", 
    UnityEngine.Color.green, null, uplayer.SteamPlayer(), 
    EChatMode.GLOBAL, null, true);
                        player.Heal(40);
                    }
                }

            }
            protected override void Unload()
            {
                UnturnedPlayerEvents.OnPlayerInventoryRemoved -= 
    UnturnedPlayerEvents_OnPlayerInventoryRemoved;
            }

        }
    }
    ```

